# How do I toggle CSS features with JS functions

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I want to run my function which then starts displaying a CSS element, I currently have

CSS

```
.popUpNames{
  color:white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px white;
  padding:5px;
  border:black 5px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display:block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  visibility: hidden;
}

.popUpNames .show {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="popUpNames">
    <p></p>
  </div>
```

JS

```
function togglePopup() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("popUpNames");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

(the function is called within another function, the calling of the function itself works)

I've tried to chnange the id's to classes, the order of .popUpNames .show and the regular .popUpNames

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_popup I tried extrapolating it from this website, but to no avail

Comment: `getElementById` is **only** about `id` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TechStudent10 is right about needing to change `.popUpNames .show` to `.popUpNames.show`. You also need to do a couple other things:

- Change `document.getElementById("popUpNames")` to `document.querySelector(".popUpNames")`
- Remember to call `togglePopup()` after the DOM has loaded (otherwise it'll stay hidden).

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  togglePopup();
});

function togglePopup() {
  const popup = document.querySelector(".popUpNames");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.popUpNames {
  color:white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px white;
  padding:5px;
  border:black 5px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: none;
}

.popUpNames.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="popUpNames">
  <p>paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You added a space between `.popUpNames` and `.show` in your CSS file. This is going to apply this style to elements that have `.popUpNames` *or* `.show`. Not and. In order to fix this, remove the space between the two classes so that you have `.popUpNames.show`.

```css
.popUpNames {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px white;
  padding: 5px;
  border: black 5px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.popUpNames.show {
  display: block;
}
```

I also removed the `visibility` property because you are already using `display`.

Another thing (pointed out by @Mister Jojo) is that you are getting the element using the `getElementById` function, but you haven't even assigned an ID to your HTML element. Add an ID to your HTML element by adding `id="<your id here>"` to it.

Comment: The space in the selector is called a [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator). Not using a combinator between selectors makes them a [compound selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#compound_selector).